Is it possible to record the frames generated by Compose / displayed by my Android app?
When using a system trace one can see how long it took to create a frame. Is it also somehow possible to record all frames (the content of the frame/like a screenshot) drawn by my app along with a system trace? Would make it easier to "navigate" a system trace.
Further I would like to use this to check if my composable draws what I expect starting from the first frame or if it maybe draws the first frame wrong and starts to draw as expected on the second frame. Which I as a human might not notice, but I would like to check for learning purposes.

If your app renders content to a SurfaceView/TextureView, you can use a SurfaceTexture to obtain frames from the rendering surface or you can use MediaProjection API this allows you to capture the contents of the screen and record them as a video or capture individual frames.

@Maveňツ Using that API, is it possible to record my whole app or would one have to code a recording function for each screen? Can you post an example as answer?

couldnt test it myself yet due to lack of time, but looks promising, accepted :-) Noticed you use findViewById - do you have a Jetpack Compose variant of this too?
